# .NET Framework 4 Extended?

Tags: uninstall, .net-framework, sql-server

### To avoid XY, I will preface with the following:

I am trying to uninstall an unneeded installation of MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on a production server.  The server is also running SQL Server 2008 Express, which is being used by Sharepoint.

We need to remove SQL Server 2008 R2.  1) It is unlicensed and 2) It is causing conflicts with our backup solution licensing.

I tried uninstalling 2008R2 from the control panel.  The installation goes and says its successful.  However, it didnt actually do anything.

I came across some articles that say uninstall all the .NET Frameworks and then perform the uninstall.  After uninstall, reinstall the .NET Frameworks

### The Question

OK, so I looked and I see the following on the server

- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
- .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- .NET Framework 4 Extended
- .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack

I found the downloads for all of them except for the .NET Framework 4 Extended.  I can not find where to download it.  Or is it part of something else?

Comment: You sure you have `.NET Framework 5` and not `.NET Framework 4.5` there is a huge difference. One exists the other does not. `.NET Framework 4.5.1` is the next version of the `.NET Framework` currently in testing.

Comment: yeah its 4, just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download it here:

**Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation that is the "Extended"

Comment: Full = Client + Extended. The Client only installer has a separate download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24872

Comment: ok, Ill test it on a VM and see

Comment: works, just tested it.